# AMD: Role of app.js

Tags: yeoman

What special role has "app.js" (it says *global define*, but I don't know why or where I need that), and why doesn't it compile to CoffeeScript, or at least not more than once?

I'm using the latest version of Yo.

Comment: Which generator with which options did you use?

Comment: No generator, just `yo webapp` with "Y" to everything...